# how to filter the data from varchar column mysql

Tags: mysql

We have data into our database

```
id: 1 name: 100 abc
id: 2 name: 200 xyz
id: 3 name: 1000 kku
id: 4 name: 12 yog
id: 5 name: 1 ton

SELECT id from table where name = '${result['name']}'
```

If someone put into result 100 ABc it will not match because our db has 100 abc, So how can we fix it please guide

I mean it should return me id : 1 if someone put

```
SELECT id from table where name = '100 ABC' or SELECT id from table where name = '100abc'
```

Comment: Specify case-independent COLLATE during the comparing. Or, if the case makes no sense for values in all cases - alter the column's collation.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Akina Did you mean 'case-insensitive'?

Comment: @Strawberry You're right.

Answer (score -1):

The typical way you would handle this would be to just lowercase both of the comparison, e.g.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = LOWER('100 ABC');
```

A better approach, however, would be to only store lowercase in the table, and then only pass in lowercase data from your application layer.  You could consider using a lowercase collation in MySQL for this, but you could also enforce this from the application.

Comment: Thanking you for response. What about if anyone removes between spaces e.g into our db we have 100 abc if request came with 100abc then ?

Comment: It shouldn't really be the database's responsibility to scrub the inputs, that should happen in your application.  I can't give a general answer to your follow-up question.

Comment: @ZahreenKhan Remove spaces from both column' value and user input unconditionally, for example... but anycase you may receive excess rows (except the tokens charslists not interfere).

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    id
FROM
    `table_name`
WHERE
   LOWER(REPLACE(`name`, ' ', '')) = LOWER(REPLACE('100 abc', ' ', ''));
```

Comment: For all the combinations of user_input, you can convert `name` column value and user_input value to LOWERCASE and replace blank spaces and compare one single word. it gives you accurate output.

Comment: For your reference : REPLACE function - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp